# Solr on Docker:localhost:8983 not working

Tags: solr, docker

I followed the steps mentioned in https://hub.docker.com/_/solr/ and installed solr in my docker container on windows.

Accessing the admin console : http://localhost:8983/solr throws "ERR_Connection_Refused".

Output of docker ps -a :

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                             COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                           PORTS
ca473cca4747        solr5.5.0        "/opt/solr/bin/solr -"   19 minutes ago      Up 19 minutes                    0.0.0.0:8983->8983/tcp
```

I can create a core successfully by running

```
docker exec -it --user=solr my_solr bin/solr create_core -c gettingstarted
```

Checking the solr status within the docker container:

```
Found 1 Solr nodes:

Solr process 1 running on port 8983
{
  "solr_home":"/opt/solr/server/solr",
  "version":"5.5.0 2a228b3920a07f930f7afb6a42d0d20e184a943c - mike - 2016-02-16 15:22:52",
  "startTime":"2016-03-19T16:23:03.215Z",
  "uptime":"0 days, 0 hours, 22 minutes, 29 seconds",
  "memory":"39.3 MB (%8) of 490.7 MB"}
```

Butstill http://localhost:8983/solr nor http://localhost:8983/solr/admin not accessible

Comment: What is the host OS? Would you happen to be using Docker Machine?

Comment: Yes am using docker-machine on windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you mentioned you are using Docker Machine on Windows the way you access published ports is a little different than on native Linux. Docker Machine has created a virtual machine on your laptop which is running Linux to support Docker. This virtual machine has its own IP address. You can get the IP address by running `docker-machine ip` or `docker-machine ip <machine_name>` and replacing `<machine_name>` with the actual name of your Docker Machine if different than `default`.

You would then access the published port using that VM IP address. On my local Mac with Docker Machine it would be http://192.168.99.100:8983/solr/admin. It is likely a similar IP address on Windows as well.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing you can try is to talk to Solr webserver using `0.0.0.0` instead of `localhost`:

```
http://0.0.0.0:8983/solr
```

Request to `GET http://localhost:8983/solr` not responded for me neither (just stuck without any response)

Worked for me at following environment:

- linux
- solr container runs in swarm
- solr container has published 8983 port
- solr:7.7.1-alpine
- accessing solr ui from node where container runs